# Problema de Conexión a directorio de Windows Server 2003 R2

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, windows-server-2012

Estoy tratando con esta aplicación leer un archivo .jpg en un Servidor remoto
 Windows Server 2003 R2.

Para esto en un proyecto **WebForm** ocupe **NetworkConnection**

Intuitivamente he dado valor a algunos parámetros que se ocupan 
 pero tengo duda con ellos

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
**using (NetworkConnection nc = new NetworkConnection(localName, networkName, 
objnetCred))**
```

localName =  "F:"                         *<< Duda donde puedo encontrar 
                                                  este valor en mi red y cual 
                                                   seria su formato*

networkName = "servidor_99"               *<< Duda donde puedo encontrar 
                                                este valor en mi red y cual 
                                                   seria su formato*

objnetCred =

Domain   "999.999.99.999"            *<< Duda donde puedo encontrar 
                                          este valor en mi red y cual 
                                          seria su formato*

Password "xxxxxxxxxx"

UserName "usernamexxx"

```
**var result = WNetAddConnection2(
           netResource,
           credentials.Password,
           credentials.UserName,
           flags);**
```

netResource

```
         Comment           null

         Display Type      Share

         LocalName         "F:"

         Provider          null

         RemoteName        "servidor_99"

         ResourceType      Disk

         Scope             GlobalNetwork

         Usage             0
```

credentials.Password          "xxxxxxxxxx"

credentials.UserName          "usernamexxx"

flags                         1

Con estos valores me da el error:

El valor de result es igual a 67

***No se encuentra el nombre de red especificado***

Agradecería alguna orientación al respecto

Saludos

Comment: No entiendo que relacion tiene el `NetworkConnection` con `Sql Server`, si el archivo esta integrado como registro en una tabla debes realizar un SELECT para obtener el dato. Unabase de datos no se accede como archivo

Comment: Gracias por señalarme el Servidor es WINDOWS SERVER 2003 R2

Comment: pero el servidor no influye en nada con sql server, no queda claro que es lo que quieres conseguir, porque planteas servicios y clases que no se relacionan

Comment: sabes lo que es `Sql Server` ?

Comment: Sql Server es capaz de interactuar con el sistema de archivos y de red, pero para tu proyecto parace no aplicar en lo mas mínimo, es mejor trabajar con carpetas de red, Deberias volver a redactar tu problema.

Comment: Si Sql Server es capaz de interactuar con el sistema de archivos. Dame un ejemplo para hacerlo de esa manera te lo agradeceria mucho. Gracias por el interes.

Comment: Gracias al comentario de Faustus Una posible solución la encontre aqui :   https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/8f949660-9a6a-4d03-ad18-d5302f154ac1/insertar-una-imagen-sql?forum=sqlserveres